# postfix: how do I set virtual mailbox to create null client?

Tags: postfix, null-client

I have a simple mail server, using vhost/vmaps to create virtual mailboxes.

here is my current setting:

```
www logs # postfix | grep virtual
...
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_lock = fcntl, dotlock
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps

www logs # cd /etc/postfix
www postfix # ls
dynamicmaps.cf  post-install    recipient_bcc     vhosts
main.cf         postfix-files   recipient_bcc.db  vmaps
master.cf       postfix-script  sasl              vmaps.db
www postfix # cat vhosts
myserver.com
www postfix # cat vmaps
root@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
postmaster@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
fmaster@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
abuse@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
survey@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
admin@myserver.com myserver.com/admin/
```

I want to create another mailbox, to `no-reply@myserver.com`, that every mail sent to this account gets thrown to `/dev/null` automatically.

How should I edit my main.cf/virtual domains/virtual maps?

I tried

```
no-reply@myserver.com myserver.com/../../dev/null
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

Create local user

```
# useradd -s /sbin/nologin -d /dev/null no-reply
# passwd no-reply
```

Add the following line to the /etc/aliases

```
no-reply: /dev/null
```

Point no-reply@myserver.com to the local user

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
```

/etc/postfix/virtual_alias

```
no-reply@myserver.com no-reply
```

Create all necessary maps

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_alias
# postmap /etc/aliases
```

And don't forget restart the postfix

Comment: In my case it was necessary to use `no-reply@localhost` in the virtual alias table to use the *local* transport